# PHPUnit with @runInSeparateProcess-annotation is freezing, is there something I can do about it?

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

First of all I'm using PhpStorm 2021.2.3 with PHPUnit 9.5.10 in a dockerized environment.

When I'm testing my `Router.php` or my `Factory.php` I'm using the [`@runInSeparateProcess`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#runinseparateprocess)-annotation in some of the test methods, otherwise they would throw me an error:

> session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent

Which makes sense and is the reason to use the `@runInSeparateProcess`-annotation for me. Is this a valid use case? Should I do it differently?

The problem with the `@runInSeparateProcess`-annotation I got is that if I run my tests in PhpStorm **with Coverage** then the **tests freeze** when it gets to the tests with the said annotation and it won't continue.

I read that it has something to do with the connection limit of PHP, but I don't quite understand what I can do about it.

Comment: Can be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20946 . What's your Xdebug settings? Is it trying to connect to the IDE when tests are run (`xdebug.start_with_request` in Xdebug v3)? Can you run some simple test (no process separation should needed for this) and show what `xdebug_info();` will show there?

Comment: The "connection limit of **PHP**" does not apply here. PHP itself doesn't really have such a thing, as that's usually the domain of web servers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar some years back where I was shelling out of PHP to call a HTTP API on the same application. Granted, I didn't really know why I was doing at the time, but what I did figure out was that I wanted to have the same `$_SESSION` in both parent and child processes.

When using default sessions, PHP places a lock on the session data file. This is so that two processes can't open and read/write the contents of the file at the same time. The second process will simply lock.

This is clear to see if you have a web script that opens the session and sleeps for 10 seconds. If you access that script 10 times concurrently AND pass the same session cookie in for each request, then each request will wait for a previous one to complete and release the lock on the file. The total time taken will be 100 seconds.

Anyway getting back to the issue at hand, if you suspect it's a session issue your options are to either not start the session, or use `session_write_close()` just prior to shelling out to your child process. Beware of any side effects of this.